# why does my terraform not working with minikube?

Tags: terraform

I am trying to launch pods using terraform in minikube. While running terraform[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMFsW.png) apply I am getting an error, "zip: not a valid zip file".

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context_cluster = "minikube"
}
resource "kubernetes_pod" "echo" {
  metadata {
    name = "echo-example"
    labels {
      App = "echo"
  } }
  spec {
    container {
      image = "hashicorp/http-echo:0.2.1"
      name  = "example2"
      args = ["-listen=:80", "-text='Hello World'"]
      port {
        container_port = 80
} 
}
}
}
```

Comment: You really should try and format your terraform file better

Comment: The error should not be an image but instead should be as text directly in the question (in code blocks to make it readable). As mentioned you should also consider running `terraform fmt` on your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Finally, the Terraform commands work on a directory, not an individual file. Do you get the same error if you run `terraform plan` or `terraform plan .`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of similar cases. For example [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22396) issue
You need to move your individual tf files to their own directories, and then you can point terraform to that directory.

The plan command only accepts directories, and the apply command will only take the entire dir, or plan output file (use -out on plan). I think this limitation is due to the fact that terraform requires a state file for each plan. Here is how I've setup my terraform project, note secrets.tfvars and terraform.tfvars are common between both terraform plans.

```
$ tree
.
├── 1-base
│   ├── provider.tf
│   ├── backend.tf
│   └── core.tf
├── 2-k8s
│   ├── 1-k8s.tf
│   ├── 2-helm.tf
│   ├── apps
│   ├── provider.tf
│   ├── backend.tf
│   ├── chart-builds
│   └── charts
├── secrets.tfvars
├── terraform.tfvars
└── todo.md

#From here you can run:

$ terraform init -var-file=secrets.tfvars ./1-base
$ terraform plan -var-file=secrets.tfvars ./1-base
```