# using terraform with helm on minikube gives error

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I have the following .tf file

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_context_cluster = "minikube"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "user-namespace" {
   metadata {
     name = "user-namespace"
   }
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_context_cluster = "minikube"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "local" {
  name  = "user-server-chart"
  chart = "./user-server"
}
```

When I run `terraform apply` I get the following error

kubernetes_namespace.brw-user-namespace: Creating...
helm_release.local: Creating...

Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation.\n") has prevented the request from succeeding (post namespaces)
│
│   with kubernetes_namespace.user-namespace,
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "user-namespace":
│    5: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "user-namespace" {
│
╵

Kubernetes cluster unreachable: invalid configuration: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
│
│   with helm_release.local,
│   on main.tf line 17, in resource "helm_release" "local":
│   17: resource "helm_release" "local" {

Comment: refer the below link. may be useful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62445390/why-does-my-terraform-not-working-with-minikube

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: kubeconfig is not having the correct context and add a line with kubeconfig to your ~/.bashrc file
**kubectl config set-context ~/.kube/kubeconfig1.yml**
**kubectl config use-context ~/.kube/kubeconfig1.yml**
or **export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/<kubeconfig_env>.yml**

Step 2: A Helm Release resource can be imported using its namespace and name
e.g. **terraform import helm_release.example default/example-name**
Since the repository attribute is not being continued as metadata by helm, it will not be set to any value by default. All other provider specific attributes will be set to their default values and they can be overridden after running apply using the resource definition configuration.

You may refer to the document [1] [2] for additional information.
[1] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release
[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs